# hashlib.sha256 yields unexpected result

Tags: python, cryptography

I'm trying to implement the following steps in Python:

```
Compressed public key:
02F840A04114081690223B7069071A70D6DABB891763B638CC20C7EC3BD58E6C86

SHA-256 of public key yields:
cb05d0fd5e76ba8ea88323fc5d3eefd09a78d8e2a5fd4955307b549657a31330
```

This step is fairly simple, so I wrote this piece of code to see if it works as planned:

```
from binascii import hexlify
from hashlib import sha256
master_key = hexlify("02F840A04114081690223B7069071A70D6DABB891763B638CC20C7EC3BD58E6C86")
print(sha256(master_key).hexdigest())
```

However, this doesn't yield the expected result. Instead it gives me:

```
cee4b5650664b11623675d0371ab9dd1e3478758a95b189e54ecf8b7bdd7ba2d
```

Using the string without hex-encoding it first doesn't yield the correct result either. Any ideas?

Comment: You're using `hexlify()` to convert the hex representation of the key to hex. It's already in hex. You probably want to use `unhexlify()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to [`unhexlify`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify) your hexadecimal representation:

```
from binascii import unhexlify
from hashlib import sha256
master_key = unhexlify("02F840A04114081690223B7069071A70D6DABB891763B638CC20C7EC3BD58E6C86")
print(sha256(master_key).hexdigest())
# cb05d0fd5e76ba8ea88323fc5d3eefd09a78d8e2a5fd4955307b549657a31330
```

Comment: That is what happens when you have no clue what hexadecimal actually looks like. Thank you!

Is there any chance you were ever part of the ArmA 2 community?

Comment: the what?! and... no. sorry.